# Insert into MySQL - IF t1.count(*) < t2.available

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have two MySQL tables. One table is a list of prizes and the other table is a list of winners. There can be multiple of a type of prize available.

**prize**

- id
- name
- available

**winner**

- name
- prize_id

If there are 3 of a prize available, and only 2 winners currently have that prize listed as their `prize_id`, I want to insert the next winner.

I have tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO winner (name, prize_id) 
SELECT 'steve', 1
FROM winner, prize
WHERE (select if(count(w.id) < p.available, 1, 0) as `valid` 
       from prize p, winner w 
       where p.id = 1 and w.prize_id = p.id) = 1
```

If I trim it down to this, it sort of work but will insert as many rows as exist in the `prize` table

```
INSERT INTO prize (name, prize_id)  
SELECT 'steve', 1 
FROM winner   
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Is there a way I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

```
INSERT INTO winner (name, prize_id) 
SELECT tempwinner.name , tempwinner.prize_id
from
(Select 
column1, column2
    FROM winner inner join prize p on (w.prize_id = p.id)
    WHERE p.id = 1 and count(w.id) < p.available
) tempwinner
```